# Pandas groupby and pct_change(periods=n) to Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Can you please kindly suggest how to convert below pandas statement to pure numpy?
Thank you very much.

```
df.groupby(['column'])['new_column'].pct_change(periods=30)
```

Comment: That's somewhat of a peculiar request. `numpy` doesn't really have groupby functionality so it gets complicated. Is there a practical reason you are looking to do this?

Comment: Thanks @ALollz. I am trying speed up my calculations. DF is huge so I decided to convert to Numpy and wrap everything in numba's njit and vectorize decorators. Seeing big improvements for parts of the code that I was able to convert.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right you want to convert it into an array.

`np.array(list(df_decade['Close'].pct_change(periods = -1)))`